# Order By Problem T-Sql

Tags: t-sql

I have a sql statement I am using a simple sort such as the following

```
Select numbers
From theTable
Order By numbers
```

What I get in return is the following

```
1
11
12
14
2
21
22
23
3
35
37
etc...
```

I want it to be ordered in normal order

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column you are selecting isn't stored as a numeric value. You need to cast it to a some kind of number before orderby will behave the way you want.

It should be as easy as:

```
select numbers from order orderby cast(numbers as int)
```

As long as long as all the values in that column cast properly.

Comment: The second one should work, as long as no actual text characters snuck into the Numbers field.

Comment: order by won't work on renamed column. The second example will work, if he has only number values in his column.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: If a letter comes in then 1 10 11 2 21 is the correct order anyway.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik:  Yes, my point was that a CAST won't work in the order by if there is at least one letter in the Numbers column because then CAST will throw an error

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: And my point was that if the column permitted such non-numeric values, ordering it by numerical representation of its value doesn't make any sense any more.

Answer (score 0):

what's the datatype of the column storing the numbers?  Convert/cast it to an int and you should get what you expect.